# Tem como retornar 2 valor em um Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho o seguinte script:

```
('#AjaxUpdateClient').submit(function(e){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");

    var form = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/updateClient",
        data: form,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(){
        }
    });
});
```

será usado para atualização de um cadastro no banco de dados, porem eu vou precisar que ele envie o `POST` e também o `id` pela `var id`, existe alguma forma de o `data:` retorna o `form, id`? agradeço!

**EDITADO**

Da parte do servidor tenho um método update, que vai receber o $_POST na variável `$params` eu queria receber o `id` separado do `$_POST` para eu passar no segundo parâmetro do método, tentei receber o id junto do $_POST porem não funcionou..

```
//Update on database
public function update($params, $id)
{
    $params_fields = "`".implode("`= ?, `", array_keys($params))."`= ?";

    $query  = "UPDATE `{$this->table}` SET {$params_fields} WHERE `id`= ?";
    $stmt   = $this->db->prepare($query);

    $i=1;
    foreach($params as $key => $value){
        $stmt->bindValue($i, $value);
        $i++;
    }
    $stmt->bindValue($i, $id);

    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt;
}
```

Comment: Quando dizes _"o id capturado"_ referes-te a `var id = $(this).attr("id");`?

Comment: Ou a pergunta está equivocada, ou não entendi. O parâmetro `data`  não retorna nada, apenas envia. O que retorna é o `json`, e nele, você pode retornar o que quiser, no script que roda em `/updateClient`.

Comment: Exatamente "enviar", e sim o id capturado na `var id`.

Comment: Podes explicar  que tipo de informação envias e o que precisas saber do servidor? já tens algum código da parte do servidor?

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta vê se deu pra ser mais específico.

Comment: Você poderia mudar a url pra que ela contenha o id, updateClient/21 , por exemplo, e no servidor pegar o id da url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tens várias alternativas, uma é juntar o ID ao `..serialize()`, outra é enviar um objeto com duas chaves.

O `.serialize()` gera uma _string`de chaves e valores, tipo _querystring_ onde as chaves e valores são aglomerados por`&`. Assim juntando`&id=teuID` envias o que queres para o PHP. Poderia ser assim:

```
$('#AjaxUpdateClient').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = this.id;
    var form = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/updateClient",
        data: form + '&id=' + id,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(res){
            console.log(res);
        }
    });
});
```

A outra alternativa seria usando o `.serializeArray()` que gera uma array de objetos. E depois no jQuery podias usar assim:

```
$('#AjaxUpdateClient').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = this.id;
    var form = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/updateClient",
        data: {form: form, id: id},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(res){
            console.log(res);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Vou te passar duas formas funcionais:

1. Passar o `id` pelo método `GET`, adicionando o valor no `action` do `form`:

**Formulário:**

```
<form action="pagina.php?id=123" method="post">
    <!-- [...] -->
</form>
```

**Script:**

```
var dados = $( '#MeuFormulario' ).serialize();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $('#MeuFormulario').attr('action'),
    data: dados
});
```

---

2. Passar o `id` pelo método `POST`, adicionando `inputs` do tipo `hidden`:

**Formulário:**

```
<form action="pagina.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="123">
    <!-- [...] -->
</form>
```

**Script:**

```
var dados = $( '#MeuFormulario' ).serialize();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $('#MeuFormulario').attr('action'),
    data: dados
});
```

---

Note que o script é o mesmo e a `url` é o próprio `action` do `form`. E na página que vai tratar os dados, é só receber normalmente com `$_GET['id']` / `$_POST['id']`, conforme o método utilizado.